# com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : javaee__pm

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, resources, glassfish

I am have a small JavaEE JSF application that access to a mysql database through persistance JPA and it work well in my netbeans and glassfish enviroment. The thing is, after cloning it in other machine with same configuration (netbeans, glasfish, same database) it won't run. I guess it is caused by the database configuration but I tried to configure it in the new machine and it is hopeless. it always give the same error:

```
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
/home/alvarob/NetBeansProjects/WordPracticeJavaEE/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1032: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

And this is part of the GlassFish log:

```
[2015-10-19T14:47:13.556+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1445255233556] [levelValue: 1000] [[
    Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : javaee__pm
    com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : javaee__pm
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
... *it continues*
```

And this is my .gitignore (Maybe am I missing some important file?)

```
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
nbactions.xml
nb-configuration.xml
.nb-gradle/

*.class

.mtj.tmp/

*.janr
*.war
*.ear
```

Comment: @BalusC why did you modify my title like that? I always saw that the title is a question or a summary about one issue. Instead modify my title could you help me with the issue itself?

Comment: You got an exception. That's the issue. I just put the concrete issue in title. In case of exceptions, programmers normally google for exception+message in order to find answers/clues. Having them in title makes it easier to find for them (and also for you ...)

Comment: Ok I didn't realize this is the way to go with titles, every day I learn something new. thank you.

Comment: Glassfish cannot find the specified JDBC Resource "javaee" (your database). Have you configured the resource/mysql on the glassfish server? When you have, show us the configuration. There are at least 3 ways to configure it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by creating in the target machine a JDBC pool and JSBC resource with exactly the same name and configuration than in my computer.